# jQuery_ui slider doesn't load for anonymous user

Tags: 7, users, javascript

In my recent **drupal 7** install... I've installed **jquery_update**. I configured it, and added a little module with a js.

**jQuery_ui** is not loaded for anonymous use. I've done some researches on the web ... for most people jquery doesn't load for anonymous user because it wasn't called. But for me jquery loads correctly I can `alert(jQuery("#amount"))` succesfully.

My error message is **`TypeError: jQuery(...).slider is not a function`** : jquery_ui slider method is not loaded for anonymous user... I searched in permissions too.. no jquery_ui permission configuration.

What did I missed ? Couls anyone help ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the quick answer : Add this line in the module using jquery_ui to call jquery_ui when needed.

```
drupal_add_js('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js', 'external');
```

or this:

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'jquery_update') .'/replace/ui/ui/minified/jquery-ui.min.js');
```

The question now is : is this the best way?

Comment: I can't get jQuery UI to load at all when I log out of Drupal... using the latest jQuery Update module.